# what is the meaning of "connection refused" in typical jdbc drivers?

Tags: jdbc

When we receive a connection failures in jdbc it can mean :

- security / privileges for user are bad or
- something wrong on the server or port
- ...

So, when a "connection" is "refused", who is refusing the connection and what tools can we use to determine why?   It seems as though this is an implementation specific detail of the driver, but am just curious if there is a "right" way to debug this, at the interface layer rather then having to look at Driver implementation specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we receive a connection error in jdbc it can mean :
>
> security / privileges for user are bad or

No.

> something wrong on the server or port

Yes. The database server isn't running at the host:port specified.

> So, when a "connection" is "refused", who is refusing the connection

The target host's TCP stack.

> and what tools can we use to determine why?

There is only one reason why, see above.

Note however that some JDBC drivers report this condition differently. For example, Oracle uses the bizarre and thoroughly misleading message 'The network adapter could not connect' or similar.